# Drupal form api output as raw HTML

Tags: html, forms, cordova, drupal-7, phonegap

**How might I access the raw HTML generated for a form by the Drupal Form API?**

Recently, I finished a long and difficult task of building custom forms in Drupal. I am very familiar and comfortable with the Drupal form API system so all the work was very strongly based on the Form API.

**However, those Drupal forms I created also need to be represented in a Phonegap app.**

So, I have began thinking about how to extract the form data from Drupal in order to create the same forms in Phonegap.

Then it occurred to me *if I can somehow programmatically download the raw HTML the Form API generates in Drupal, I can just copy and past into Phonegap*.

Is it possible to programmatically access the raw HTML data output by the Drupal Form API?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use render() function.

So for example your function that build form called `my_form()`.
Then you just need get this form with `drupal_get_form('my_form')`
and render it with `render()` function.

```
function my_form_html() {
  $form = drupal_get_form('my_form');
  $html = render($form);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon. render does not successfully output all the form markup. I used the 2 functions you indicated. Select lists showed correctly but radio buttons did not.